# Font Awesome 5: Possible to change BACKGROUND-COLOR of icon so it doesn't bleed outside border?

Tags: icons, background-color, font-awesome-5

I'd like to change the BACKGROUND-COLOR of a Font Awesome 5 icon. Unfortunately, when I specify the background-color it bleeds outside the icon's border.

Here is a sample:

```
<i class="far fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color: #000; font-size: 5em; background-color: yellow;"></i>
```

[image]

I am not surprised it acts like this, but is this possible to do?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posed this question to the very helpful Font Awesome support and was directed to use their built-in layering and power transforms to create custom icons.

> **Note**: This solution only works if you're using the [SVG + JS](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=svg-with-js) version of Font Awesome.

```html
 <span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-5x">
    <i class="fas fa-triangle" style="color: yellow;"></i>
    <i class="far fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color: black;"></i>
 </span
```

More reading and examples here:

https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/wxLQEL

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome is a font, so this is analogous to asking whether you can set the background color (fill) of the letter `O` in a regular font, which isn't possible. A font only has one color.

However, the FontAwesome font can be exported to individual SVG graphics ([here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-sprites)). If you use those rather than the font, you may be able to set the `fill` style of the SVG to obtain the desired result. If the SVG path has no fill, you can always edit the SVG so that it does.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I will give this a try.

Comment: Because of the IE limitations with using the technique you mentioned I simply used the SVG graphic and created my own icon. Thanks.